# Dealing with large organization

Tags: interviewing

I interviewed with a large organization in February of this year. The interview went well. I have been in touch with HR since then, but the only thing that has been certain is that my file is still under review.

During the questioning, the interviewer wanted to know if I would also be interested in being an intern. I said no at the time, but now I wish I had said yes because an internship is more appropriate for where I am at right now in terms of my career development. It is now August, but I have not been rejected and my file is still under review according to HR. One of my colleagues who also applied was rejected months ago, but I have been stuck in limbo. Would it be a bad idea at this point to e-mail the HR person to express my change of heart as far as my interest is concerned in an internship? Or should I just move on because it is too late? I'd really like to work for this organization.

Comment: I am not sure if the size of the organization has anything to do with it. What position did you apply for? Was it for a specific opening or was it just a general interview?

Comment: Are you hoping to work there? Are you just curious? Can you [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking? It's hard to provide an answer/insight without knowing a bit more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @enderland What part of "I'd really like to work for this organization." doesn't answer your first question?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep This was a general interview for particular division that aligns with my expertise. I applied very far from my graduation time (years) and so it is natural for them to not move fast on this.

Comment: So are you asking more or less how to reach out to HR at a company you haven't heard from in a long time? Do you want to have an internship with that company?

Comment: When I see sciencenewbie and see chemistry and physics sites in your profile, it looks like you're a lab rat. 'Large organization' in that context sounds like a university hospital or perhaps government lab. It's possible that this is hung up because the people that need to say yes are out on extended leaves or conferences.  In such circumstances you should 'take anything' - if you can intern then do it.  If they have any opening you can fill take it - just get your foot in the door.  Rather than say 'I'll be an intern', tell them you'll come in as a lab assistant if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be honest.

If you really like to work for this organisation,get in touch with them and honestly explain your reasoning behind saying no the last time , and expressing interest now.

Whether or not they will be convinced is a different matter but at least you would have taken a shot and expressed you change of mind (and your reasons behind it).

Note - I am assuming here that you mindset change is not influenced in any way due to not hearing from them for a while and you are genuinely interested in taking an internship now. This will be the key bias to watch out for.